How to add your own modifier via Python
I'm very new to the scripting scene.
I want to create and add my own modifier in the modifiers panel so I can work with it there rather than needing to deal with the script itself. I looked and saw that the bpy_struct is the parent class of all of the modifiers in Blender, however I also saw something saying that it can't be accessed.
When I tried creating a class with it as the parent my code threw an error stating that bpy_struct is not defined. Is there something I'm missing?

AFAIK you cannot write your own modifiers except you compile a custom Blender version by yourself.

Can't you create your modifier using Geometry nodes, put them all in a Group, and then add your required inputs to the group? That way they will appear as inputs in the modifiers panel just like other modifier types. See the Blender Manual and tutorials on using geometry nodes.

Given the python tag, Chris is correct, you can't write a modifier in Python. But you can in geonodes. The explanation on why you can't do it using Python will be similar to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/311150/60486

Geometry nodes is a hell. Even 10 lines of mathematical code of vector manipulation in the form of nodes turn into an unreadable mishmash of spaghetti.
